# Why don't instance methods work as expected?

Tags: javascript, oop

```
(function() {
     window.gArr = new ExtArray();
})();

function ExtArray() {
     this.bounce = function() {
         document.write("Bounced successfully!");
     };
}

ExtArray.prototype = new Array;
ExtArray.prototype.first = function() {
     document.write(this[0]);
}

var eArr = new ExtArray();
//all three work
eArr.bounce();
eArr.push("I am first! ");
eArr.first();
// invoking global
gArr.bounce(); // it works
gArr.push("No, it is me who is really first! "); // doesn't work
gArr.first(); // doesn't work
```

Why doesn't it work?

Comment: What is the observed behaviour?  What is the expected behaviour?  How do they differ?

Comment: gArr.push should work and gArr.first() should output "No, it is me who is really first! "

Comment: "Note that the prototype of an constructor function can be altered at any point. If we re-assign the area of our rect, then new instances of rect will have a different area method to the first few instances. Changing the prototype does not affect instances of created objects." Reference: http://xhalent.wordpress.com/2011/02/16/javascript-object-instantiation-and-prototypes/

Answer (score 1):

```
> (function() {
>      window.gArr = new ExtArray(); })();
```

Why is that preferred to just:

```
var gArr = new ExtArray();
```

they are functionally identical (unless there is no *window* object in which case the first will fail);

```
> function ExtArray() {
>      this.bounce = function() {
>          document.write("Bounced successfully!");
>      }; }
```

Using *document.write* after the page has finished loading will first clear the *entire* document (i.e. everything between the HTML tags) and write whatever is passed to the function (in this case, a two word string).

```
> ExtArray.prototype = new Array;
> ExtArray.prototype.first = function() {
>      document.write(this[0]); 
> }
```

As above, *document.write* is destructive.

```
> var eArr = new ExtArray(); 
> //all three work 
> eArr.bounce();
> eArr.push("I am first! ");
> eArr.first();
```

Presumably this is running before the load event then.

```
> // invoking global 
> gArr.bounce(); // it works 
> gArr.push("No, it is me who is really first! "); // doesn't work 
> gArr.first(); // doesn't work
```

The bits that "don't work" are because you initialised *gArr* before you modified *ExtArray.prototype*, so it has the instance method *bounce* but still has the default prototype when the constructor was declared.

Remember that once declarations are done, the code runs in sequence so *gArr = new ExtArray()* runs before *ExtArray.prototype = new Array;* and so on.

Also, an instance has an internal *prototype* property that references the constructor's prototype at the instant it was created and **can't be changed** afterward (except for Mozilla's deprecated **proto** property). So changing the contsructor's prototype doesn't change the internal prototype of any instances that have already been constructed.

Answer (score 1):

You should define `window.gArr` after you define `ExtArray.prototype`:

```
function ExtArray() {
     this.bounce = function() {
         document.write("Bounced successfully!");
     };
}

ExtArray.prototype = new Array;
ExtArray.prototype.first = function() {
     document.write(this[0]);
}; // <-- semicolon will be REQUIRED here.

(function() {
    window.gArr = new ExtArray();
})();
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/Vg3Ze/

Comment: you forget `;` after define ExtArray.prototype.first

Comment: @DrStrangeLove: lostyzd is right. This would be a place where the semicolon would be crucial. Otherwise you end up *invoking* `ExtArray.prototype.first` immediately.